# How do I add sybase to php.ini?

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using scotch box on vagrant and cannot seem to find how to add mssql support. I have downloaded and installed php-sybase on the machine, but I cannot get it to show up in phpinfo(). Does anyone know what I need to set in the php.ini file?

Thanks!

Comment: enable from php.ini file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable this from php.ini file by removing the **;** sign:

```
;extension=php_sybase_ct.so
```

As like:

```
extension=php_sybase_ct.so
```

After enable restart your `APACHE`.

Comment: I've edited that because on Linux (Ubuntu) shared libraries have the ending `*.so`

Comment: acknowledged @hek2mgl

Comment: This wasn't in the php.ini file. I made sure it was the right one. But once I added, sybase showed up in phpinfo()

Comment: congratulation: yes if its not included add it because you have already installed. and one more thing, chose the best answer and mark as accepted because it will help for other who facing this issue. @JasonSpick